# bash: Emit n printable characters from a string with ANSI codes

Tags: bash, ansi-escape

In `bash`, given an arbitrary string containing [ANSI CSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) (eg colours), how do I emit a subset of the printable characters, printed in the correct colours?

Eg, given:

```
s=$'\e[0;1;31mRED\e[0;1;32mGREEN\e[0;1;33mYELLOW'
```

[image]

How do I do something like:

```
coloursubstr "$s" 0 5
```

[image]

```
coloursubstr "$s" 2 7
```

[image]

Comment: Try to ask this at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and GNU grep:

```
coloursubstr() {
  local string="$1" from="$2" num="$3"
  local line i array=()

  # fill array
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^([^m]+m)(.*)$ ]]
    for ((i=0;i<${#BASH_REMATCH[2]};i++)); do
      array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]:$i:1}")
    done
  done < <(grep -Po $'\x1b.*?m[^\x1b]*' <<< "$string")

  # print array
  for ((i=$from;i<$from+$num;i++)); do
    printf "%s" "${array[$i]}"
  done
  echo
}

s=$'\e[0;1;31mRED\e[0;1;32mGREEN\e[0;1;33mYELLOW'

coloursubstr "$s" 0 5
coloursubstr "$s" 2 7
```

Output:

[image: REDGR]
[image: DGREENY]

I assume all color codes start with `\e`, end with `m` and text is prefixed by a color code.

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer, (specific hack with magic numbers, not at all general):

```
echo "${s:0:23}"
echo "${s:0:9}${s:11:25}"
```

Output:

[image: REDGR]

[image: DGREENY]

Comment: @TomHale, Likewise, re-read `Partial`, `not ... general`.  While the above is *not* a satisfactory answer to this Q, it might be a first step or springboard idea, and the fact that it works at all may be of use for some readers.